# Create wcf web service with instanceContextMode = PerSession

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, persistence

I have a very simple service:

```
[ServiceContract]    
public interface IPncService
{
    [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebGet(UriTemplate = "set/{val}")]
    [OperationContract]
    bool SetVariable(string val);

    [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebGet(UriTemplate = "get")]
    [OperationContract]
    string GetVariableVal();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class PncService : IPncService
{
    string someVariable;

    public bool SetVariable(string val)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(val))
            return false;
        else
        {
            someVariable = val;
            return true;
        }            
    }

    public string GetVariableVal() {
        return someVariable;
    }
}
```

Why does the variable `someVariable` does not retain its value per session?

In other words if I do:

[image]

**and then go to:**

[image]

Why is the value of `someVariable = null` ? Is it a different session? I call that method on the same browser right after calling the set method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a read at this article : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2010/02/21/using-asp-net-sessions-from-wcf.aspx

Short version :

> WCF sessions are very different from ASP.NET Sessions. In short,
>
> - WCF sessions are represented as service instances (as CLR objects) and the states are part of each service instance. The sessions are
>     initiated by the calling WCF client. WCF relies on special context to
>     provide correlation for the sessions: sessionful channels, secure
>     conversations, reliable-messaging, etc.
> - ASP.NET sessions are like shared data storage across different requests. The sessions are always initiated by the server. ASP.NET
>     relies on cookies or special Uri goo to provide correlation for the
>     sessions.

Thus :

> Enabling Session States   It is very straightforward to enable the
>   ASP.NET session states. You only need to run WCF service in the
>   ASP.NET Compatibility mode as being specified in the web.config: